# Codeigniter Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdirectory

I have a CodeIgniter in my site say abc.com . I have copied full content to a sub folder in same site say abc.com/test . But I can't access the site using abc.com/test .
Can anyone help me in this regards

Thanks

Comment: better duplicate the codeigniter folder and then move it in a subfolder. I guess it would work

Comment: btw, it works for me! I tried it. Can you show the contents of your `.htacess`?

Comment: This is .htaccess file in root folder
**
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
**

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Is the .htaccess file that I am using in the test folder

Comment: PS: I have copied the complete Ci project from root folder too test folder.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting code into the comments (which makes it very hard to read). thanks.

Comment: See answer provided by @Gerben that needs to be on the root `.htaccess`, otherwise all requests will be matched by the `.htaccess` on the root. Also, consider using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` which would be better in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt|test) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why `RewriteEngine on` twice?

Comment: Don't ask me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028759/codeigniter-subfolder/14029763#comment19377409_14028759 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before everything you should check whether you have change codeginiter base url at config file.
your new base url is something like http://abc.com/test/  and rember to add slash after test/