# PHPStorm and CodeIgniter routing issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, phpstorm

I started studying CodeIgniter Web Framework and I am trying to work with PHPStorm 8.0.3 on Kubuntu 14.04. When I unzip CodeIgniter downloaded archive to root Apache folder /var/www/html and go to

```
localhost/index.php
```

then it works okay and I see "Welcome to CodeIgniter!" page.  Also I
can use

```
localhost/index.php/welcome/index
```

and see the same page as it should be.

When I created a new PHP project in PHPStorm and try

```
localhost:63342/codeignitor/index.php/
```

then I see welcome page, but if I use

```
localhost:63342/codeignitor/index.php/welcome/index
```

then I get 404 page. Also all my own controllers are not available and
cause 404.

I can call my own controller only if I make it default

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'mycontroller';
```

I think that this problem occurs because the URL contains name of my project /codeignitor/, but I'm not sure about it. So I need your advice how to set CodeIgniter environment in PHPStorm correctly to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you remove the `/index.php` and leave the rest as is

Comment: localhost:63342/codeignitor/ - I see welcome page

Comment: I ment: `localhost:63342/codeignitor/welcome/index`

Comment: `localhost:63342/codeignitor/welcome/index` - 404, unfortunately :(

Comment: I should somehow tell the CodeIgniter routing subsystem 'do not see /codeignitor/ part of URL', but I just started study it.

Comment: `localhost:63342/codeignitor/` means that you are using **PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server** (where `codeignitor/` is the Project Name). Just **define your own Deployment entry** (check Settings/Preferences) and configure it correctly (provide your URL etc) and mark it as Default for this project -- now PhpStorm will use that URL to open your files in a browser.

Comment: @LazyOne Depending on which PHP version there might be a posibility it was PHP's built in server

Comment: @SuperDJ Not with that URL structure (unless done on purporse, which does not make much sense (not the port but the projectName part in URL)). More info: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @OlehPomazan 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

Comment: whats the base url in config?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = ''; //empty string. I tried "localhost:63342/codeignitor" but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter uses the URL to determine routing, therefore `/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/index` and `/index.php/welcome/index` are not equal paths. I would recommend using one or the other, and adjusting your /index.php and /config/routes.php to accommodate for your desired path.

References:

> [Codeigniter Subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028759/codeigniter-subfolder)

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html